# Regex not working in RedirectMatch

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I want to match a particular regex and want to redirect it to main page. The condition is if the word 'item' is preceded by main domain then it should redirect. e.g

www.summitaviation.in/item/foobar.html  ->  www.summitaviation.in

while

www.summitaviation.in/foo/item/bar.html  -> should not redirect.

I'm using

```
RedirectMatch .*summitaviation\.in.item.*  http://www.summitaviation.in
```

but it's not working!! Please help.

Comment: For starters, the value evaluated by `RedirectMatch` is the _URL-path_ which does not include the domain.

Comment: Yes I got to know that. I'm new to this actually. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hostname isn't part of the match, you need to start with `/item`:

```
RedirectMatch ^/item/ http://www.summitaviation.in
```

If you've got multiple hosts pointing to the same document root, then you need to use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?summitaviation\.in$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^item/ http://www.summitaviation.in [L,R]
```